# How to return also all precincts which got their first vote counted

Tags: mysql

[image: Here is the image for the schema]

Basically, I have to print the timestamp when every precinct first votes. I have no idea about this one

Comment: Please update your question with textual/tabular data instead of image. Anyway, is the `timestamp` column assigned with `on update` function? Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table` and [post into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69458357/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This will get you precincts that have counted votes and it will get you first occurence

```
SELECT precinct
    ,MIN(voteDate) voteDate
FROM TABLE1
WHERE voteCounted = 1
GROUP BY precinct
```

This is considering that `Table1` has

| precinct | voteCounted | voteDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 0 | d1 |
| p2 | 0 | d2 |
| p3 | 1 | d3 |

Comment: Actually, I wanna print the Timestamp for the first vote of every precinct instead of precincts that have counted votes. :)

Comment: @Kavant my `voteDate` is equivalent to your `timestamp`. If your timestamp being updated - you have no way to record first one unless you put a trigger on your table